# Swift 2, unrecognized selector sent to instance for UIAlertController

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller, unrecognized-selector, nsexception

I am getting an error as below while I am tapping on TableView after click on Search.

**Error Below**
2016-06-03 11:20:31.578 ContactPLUS[1724:678512] Warning: Attempt to present   on
  which is already presenting (null)
st >> 
2016-06-03 11:20:32.001 ContactPLUS[1724:678512] -[_UIAlertControllerAlertPresentationController adaptivePresentationController]: 
unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1616570d0

2016-06-03 11:20:32.001 ContactPLUS[1724:678512] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '-[_UIAlertControllerAlertPresentationController adaptivePresentationController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1616570d0'

*** First throw call stack:
(0x182876e38 0x181edbf80 0x18287dccc 0x18287ac74 0x182778d1c 0x18836433c 0x1880117f8 0x187d20740 
0x187c72fd8 0x187c80990 0x1879b24a4 
0x18282c7b0 0x18282a554 0x18282a984 0x182754d10 0x18403c088 0x187a29f70 0x1000f8070 0x1822f28b8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

**My Code below**

**Going in the function**

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                                   self.searchActivityLoader.stopAnimating()
                                   self.searchActivityLoader.hidden = true
                                    self.showError(self.noDataFound)
                                }
```

Logic to display Alert controller:

```
func showError(errorStr: String){

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

        if(!errorStr.isEmpty){
            let alertController =  self.controllerUtil!.customOkAlert("Fail",buttonTitle:"OK" , alertMessage: errorStr)
            self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil) 
            //**Error comes after executing  above two lines**
        }
        self.genericArr = []

        self.contactsTableView.dataSource = self
        self.contactsTableView.reloadData()
        self.searchActivityLoader.stopAnimating()
        self.searchActivityLoader.hidden = true
    })

}
```

**///CustomeOkAlert**

//Alert controller to manage with default actions and custom messages

```
func customOkAlert(alertPageTitle: String,buttonTitle: String, alertMessage: String) -> UIAlertController
{
    let customeAlert = UIAlertController(title: alertPageTitle, message: alertMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    customeAlert.view.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    customeAlert.view.backgroundColor = utility.uicolorFromHex(0xEBEBED)
    customeAlert.view.tintColor = utility.uicolorFromHex(0x70B420)
    let cancelAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: buttonTitle, style: .Default){action in
        //do nothing
    }
    customeAlert.addAction(cancelAction)


    return customeAlert
}
```

Comment: can you post the customOkAlert() method?

Comment: Can you put a `print("someText")` inside your `showError` function to see if it gets called twice?

Answer (score 0):

The reason of `Attempt to present <UIAlertController which is already presenting` is frequent error comming, you need to add check if error message is already presented.
Following code helped me to reproduce your problem. Commenting the check int the `handleError` method will start issue reproduction:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var alertController: UIAlertController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        handleError()
        handleError()
    }

    func handleError() {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

            //commenting this check will start issue reproduction
            if self.alertController != nil {
                print("alert is already presented")
                return
            }
            self.alertController =  self.customOkAlert("Fail",buttonTitle:"OK" , alertMessage: "qweqwe")
            self.presentViewController(self.alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        })
    }

    func customOkAlert(alertPageTitle: String,buttonTitle: String, alertMessage: String) -> UIAlertController
    {
        let customeAlert = UIAlertController(title: alertPageTitle, message: alertMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        customeAlert.view.layer.cornerRadius = 10

        let cancelAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: buttonTitle, style: .Default){action in

            self.alertController = nil
        }
        customeAlert.addAction(cancelAction)


        return customeAlert
    }
}
```

Comment: B, Have tried the same one ..but it seems i am getting same error.